# PostgreSQL Many to Many relationship SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

So I have the following tables in postgesQL

```
quotes:
    id
    email
    
models:
    id
    manufacturer

quote_models:
    quote_id
    model_id
    quantity
```

And I want to return the quote with it's models, along with the sum of models quantity grouped by quote.

So I do this:

```
SELECT 
    q.id, q.email,
    SUM(qm.quantity) as total
FROM quotes as q
INNER JOIN quote_models as qm
    ON qm.quote_id = q.id
GROUP BY q.id;
```

And it works like a charm, but as soon as I want to retrieve the model data as well, like this:

```
SELECT 
    q.id, q.email,
    m.manufacturer,
    SUM(qm.quantity) as total
FROM quotes as q
INNER JOIN quote_models as qm
    ON qm.quote_id = q.id
INNER JOIN models as m
    ON m.id = qm.model_id
GROUP BY q.id;
```

postgres asks me to have m.manufacturer included in the group by clause.
When I do that, of course, I lose the total quantity count for each quote and get the quantity for each model instead.

What's the appropriate approach?

Thanks!

Comment: `sum(qm.quantity) over (partition by q.id) as total` and no group by needed I believe as it uses an analytic.  Assumes your version of postgresql supports analytical functions.

Comment: `... array_agg(m.manufacturer) as manufacturers ...`

Comment: What do you expect?  each quote line is going to be duplicated for each model right?  So the total will be repeated on each line the same value?  Show your expected results in a table format. with sample data.